# AWS: Amazon S3 - not able to "Make public via ACL" (Module 3 Guided Lab - Hosting a Static Website)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image: Unchecked the block public access]I've followed all the steps mentioned in the guide as they told me to. But I just am not able to make it public, and I have been struck with this issue since the last 3 days.

Detailed help would be really appreciated. Thank you[image]

Comment: Please edit your Question to include a link to the guide you are using.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to make public objects using any method, first you need to disable 'Block public access' option on the bucket level.

This configuration is over 'Permissions' tab of the bucket:
[image]

Edit it and uncheck 'Block all public access' (it can be customized to block making public object using specific mecanism like ACLs or access points):
[image]

---

Reference:

[Blocking public access to your Amazon S3 storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html)

Comment: Note: the Block Public Access setting could be set at the account level, not just the bucket level. Also, the brand new [disable ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) feature may be relevant.

Comment: I followed the same guide and made all these steps exactly. The issue still pursists. Do you happen to know any other instances which might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*Go to your desired bucket > Permissions > Object Ownership > Select ACLs enabled > Save changes*

Now you can make objects public using ACLs.